# Removing a tr widens other tds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to remove a table row in Javascript but when the row does disappear, the first column of the table widens, I can't figure why.

Does anyone can help me?

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="todos">
    <?php foreach ($todos as $row) : ?>
    <tr todoid="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <td class="isDone"><input type="checkbox" name="done" /></td>
        <td class="title" <?php if ($row['dueDate'] == null) echo "colspan='2'"; ?>><i class="delete fa fa-trash-o"></i> <?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <?php if ($row['dueDate'] != null) : ?>
        <td class="dueDate"><?php echo relativeDate($row['dueDate']); ?></td>
        <?php else : ?>
        <td></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And here is my js:

```
    $("tr[todoid] td.title .delete").click(deleteTodoHandler);
    ...
    function deleteTodoHandler(event) {
        console.log("deleteTodoHandler");
        $(event.target).parents("tr").remove();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because the content in one of the cells was larger and now the others are filling in that void when it was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify widths of the cells, they will expand to fit the content.

[image]

I removed the top row and the other rows adjusted since the second cell did not need a lot of space due to the large string.

If you do not want the shifting to occur, you need to set widths.

Comment: Is it possible to tell a column not to grow larger than its content, then?

Comment: You can play with text-overflow or whitespace wrapping.

Comment: Ok problem solved. I didn't figured how to fit the width to the content so I fixed it, but everything works. Thanks !